# javascript add and remove className, keep setting

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, classname

I want to make a button for night and day mode.I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964606/let-the-user-choose-between-dark-and-light-mode-save-settings-for-every-page-c) but it doesn't work for me.
when i click the button, it applies css to change background and text color and button value which is  night to day but if i click button again it doesn't work. it keeps execute "if" part not "else" part.

```js
//nightmode

var mode = localStorage.getItem("mode");

if (mode != null) {
   document.getElementById("body").classList.add(mode);
}

document.getElementById("nightButton").onclick = function() {
  

    var nightButton = document.getElementById("nightButton")
    var body = document.getElementById("body");


 if (nightButton.value = "night") {

    body.classList.add("nightMode");
    nightButton.value = "day";
    localStorage.setItem('mode', 'nightMode');

    } else {

    body.classList.remove("nightMode");
    nightButton.value = "night";
    localStorage.setItem("mode", null);
 }
};
```

```css
.nightMode {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<body id="body">

<input type="button" value="night" id="nightButton">

<div>abcd</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have a second look at how the [Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) works (what values it can handle). You will see that it can only store strings (_"The keys and the values are **always strings**"_). Therefore your `if (mode != null)` will only ever be true until you store something in `localStorage` for the key `"mode"` (_"A `DOMString` containing the value of the key. **If the key does not exist, `null` is returned**"_).

Answer (score 2):

Just change the line

```
 if (nightButton.value = "night") {
```

to

```
 if (nightButton.value == "night") {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the mode button handler. This snippet including handling of `localStorage` (can't be used in SO-snippets) can be found [@JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/6mvyk7be/)

```js
document.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  if (evt.target.id === "nightButton") {
    const body = document.body;
    body.classList.toggle("nightMode");
    evt.target.value = `set ${
      body.classList.contains("nightMode") ? "day" : "night"}`;
    document.querySelector("#currentMode").textContent = `Current mode: ${
        body.classList.contains("nightMode") ? "NIGHT" : "DAY"}`;
  }
});
```

```css
.nightMode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

body {
  margin: 2rem;
}

#currentMode {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>abcd
  <input type="button" value="set night" id="nightButton">
</div>

<div id="currentMode"></div>
```

Comment: It's in the title: _"..., keep setting"_

Comment: You can always determine the mode from the className in the body. See adjusted snippet

Comment: _"...the stored data is **saved across browser sessions**. `localStorage` is similar to sessionStorage, except that while data stored in `localStorage` **has no expiration time**"_ - Most likely OP wants to store the preference of the user so they don't have to change it on every visit...

Comment: thanks for answers. I've just started learning coding, so I have difficulties understanding answers. what I wanted to do was keep nightmode until i press daymode again even if i refresh or change the pages. i googled and found that i can use cookie or localstorage. So i paste that code above but it didn't work.

Comment: @Lee As said, localStorage can't be used in snippets here. [Here's a jsFiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/6mvyk7be/) including the localStorage manipulation you search

Answer (score 0):

there is a little error in your code.

This code: `if (nightButton.value = "night") {`

Can you change it: `if (nightButton.value == "night") {`

Example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/OJRLErL

Answer (score 0):

thank you all
I don't know if this is good codes but i tried this and it works ...

```
var mode = localStorage.getItem("mode");

document.getElementById("body").classList.add(mode);

if (mode == "nightMode") {
  document.getElementById("nightButton").value = "day"
} else {
  document.getElementById("nightButton").value = "night"
}


document.getElementById("nightButton").onclick = function () {


  var nightButton = document.getElementById("nightButton")
  var body = document.getElementById("body");


  if (nightButton.value == "night") {

    body.classList.add("nightMode");
    nightButton.value = "day";
    localStorage.setItem('mode', 'nightMode');

  } else {

    body.classList.remove("nightMode");
    nightButton.value = "night";
    localStorage.setItem("mode", "daymode");
  }
};
```